# Change Width of Custom Button

Tags: html, css

I want to center a custom `button` and I can't seem to find a solution.

I can align it but I don't know how to make the `border` smaller and not take up the whole `width` of my `h1` text

HTML:

```css
#button {
  color: #6E4E34;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid 2px #6E4E34;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="ImageMain">
  <div id="TextMain">
    <h1>Shop our Whole Selection</h1>
    <a href="#" id="button">Browse</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean you want to reduce the size of the button?? border is fine

Comment: Yes because currently it takes up the whole of the h1 text span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#button {
    color: #6E4E34;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: solid 2px #6E4E34;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    margin:0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
    width:100px;
}
```

**[Check it out](http://codepen.io/ahmedebead/pen/KWmjxp)**

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

set `#textMain` with

```
align-items: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

Snippet

```css
#TextMain {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#button {
  color: #6E4E34;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid 2px #6E4E34;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="ImageMain">
  <div id="TextMain">

    <h1>Shop our Whole Selection</h1>
    <a href="#" id="button">Browse</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, much more elegant than mine!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the align to center and the margin to auto. Just add the following enclosing div to your button.

```
<div style="margin:auto; width:200px;" align="center">
<a href="#" id="button">Browse</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `align` has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your button in a block level element. You could use a `<div>` so your markup would be;

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" id="button">Browse</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .wrapper #button {
   text-align:center; 
 }
```